# Ngx-Formly how to pass custom properties to a custom type?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I'm trying to create a `formly custom type`. I want to be able to pass a custom property with the call to a service in the field definition. For example

```
{
  key: 'city',
  type: 'customType',
  props: {
    label: 'Cities',
  },
  field: {
    customProp3: inject(CityService).getCities,
  },
}
```

I have added the `field` property by extending `FormlyFieldConfig` as follows

```
interface CustomFormlyFieldConfig extends FormlyFieldConfig {
   field?: {
     [additionalProperties: string]: any;
   };
}
```

In the `customType` component I try to access `field` but I get an empty object

What is the correct way to access the properties of this custom property?

**Update 0**

In the component class I have managed to access the custom property using `this.field.field.customProps`. I try to invoke this method but when I try I get `this.httpClient` is undefined` I expect this call to be made in the context of the service but it seems to be trying to invoke the method in the context of the component class. Any ideas? What is the correct way to go about invoking this method?

Comment: I have managed to access the custom properties through `field`. Now when doing a `console.log(this.field.field)` I get `Object { customProp3: getCities() }`. Now. How can I call this method to obtain the data? I have updated the question with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call the inject method outside of the supported context (you can read about the supported context in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/inject)). A solution would be to inject the service inside of the custom component and call the method there.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a select box, you may not need a custom element, just use:

```
{
  key: 'cities',
  id: 'cities',
  type: 'select',
  props: {
    required: true,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Cities',
    placeholder: 'e.g. Managua',
    options: this.defaultEntries, // to not display an empty list
  },
  expressionProperties: {
    'props.options': () => {
      return this.cityService.getCities(); // until you get them all
    },
  },
},
```